# Merge sort process

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, mergesort

So i was trying to understand the implementation ofthe mergeSort algorithm, but I can't get my head around how does the process flows in the beginning, while it has to divide the array. Below the sorting algorithm

```
void sort(int arr[], int l, int r) 
{ 
    if (l < r) 
    { 
        // Find the middle point 
        int m = (l+r)/2; 

        // Sort first and second halves 
        sort(arr, l, m);          //talking about 
        sort(arr , m+1, r);       //this part 

        // Merge the sorted halves 
        merge(arr, l, m, r); 
    }
```

The only model that comes to my mind that branches the array is this (considering an array {48, 34, 4, 1}):

```
m(a, l(0), r(3));
  m(a, l(0), m(1));
    m(a, l(0), m(0));
    m(a, m+1(1), r(1));
  m(a, m+1(2), r(3));
    m(a, l(2), m(2));
    m(a, m+1(3), r(3);
```

Is this the order in which the calls are being done ?
      calls :

```
    sort(arr, l, m);      
    sort(arr , m+1, r);
```

Also I can't understand why when the method arguments don't satisfy the if condition (`l<r`) the algorithm jumps back to the other side of the array and sort that.

Comment: No merging takes place until the division process produces two runs of one element each (this occurs when (l == r) and sort() just returns), and only then does the merging process begin. For top down merge sort, the order is depth first, left first. Bottom up merge sort skips all the recursive division by treating an array of n elements as n runs of size 1, and immediately starts merging pairs of runs.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the recursion, sort(...) doesn't do anything and just returns (because l == r) and the 2 sort(...) methods are done. After that, the merge comes into action, which does nothing than put 2 elements in the right order. After this happened, some other sort(...) method from the previous call is finished and so on.